# Would it be possible to use WebSockets as a poor-mans proxy?

Tags: websocket

Im thinking a web browser would fetch a document from a server, the document then sets up a websocket to the server, ie communication link.

Would it then be possible for the server to fetch any website/document the user types in and return it over the websocket and perhaps using javascript magic display it? Perhaps in an iframe? Thus the server would act as a proxy.

Why would I do this? For fun.

Answer (score 1):

If webpage has javascript then you wont be able to just replicate everything what is happening on page when it is executed on server.
As well most of things wont be possible to do.
As i understand you want to do something like remote browsing, simple example is when you have browser implementation on server, and then image from browser screen is sent constantly to client.
There is no traffic safe, you will actually increase traffic dramatically.
You can send mouse input and keyboard input events, and process them on server using websockets.
Video can be done using mjpeg. Little calculations have to be done on client side to calculate mouse coordinates within video to convert to real coordinates for server logic.

Of course there is no way of saving traffic or reducing logic on client computer, unless web page is extremely heavy, but I can't see any real examples of such need.

Comment: Yes, exactly, remote browsing. Javascript is a problem, but perhaps it is not, since fakit, this is for browsing documents not web applications. :) I was thinking of this idea as a way to circumvent censorship, if many pages toffered thisk ind of "surf documents through us" capability. What about https?